# How to get the value of the lang attribute with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I have an HTML document that looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
...
</html>
```

My question is: how to get the value of the attribute `lang` with jQuery?
I've tried `$("html").attr("lang")` but it did not work... any suggestions?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. $("html").attr("lang") works just fine for me when extrapolating from the example you have given. Can you post more details?

Comment: check if all your scripts are running (with firebug - see if no error); and also your html is valid.

Comment: May be this is a HTML vs. XHTML issue and lang attribute just don't end up in the DOM for one of them. Needs more research.

Comment: I've tried that again with an empty html document (just <html>, jquery include and the js script) and it work. but when I try to execute the same script on a complex page (gmail inbox using GreaseMonkey) it returns nothing ...

Comment: $("html").attr("lang") is working in major browser with html5 in 2015!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Access the attribute directly, ex :

```
$('html')[0].lang
```

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to use jQuery for this.

The easiest way to retrieve the `lang` attribute is to access the `lang` property on the read-only [`documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) object:

```
document.documentElement.lang;
```

Answer (score 9):

Use .attr()

`alert($('html').attr('lang'));`

Comment: I have vote myself down. I missed the part where he said what he did already.